# How to compute a minimum-delta for "remote desktop" sharing?

Tags: c#

Many free desktop sharing utility software is there in the market but i am thinking about writing own desktop share utility using c# first time for LAN only. this utility will run on two machines. first time sender apps sends complete image of it's desktop image to another machine called receiver. apps running on receiver machine just receive the image and display on it's own window. second time sender will take the current snap shot of its own desktop and compare with previous one and send only difference to second machine just to send minimum data over the network. if no difference found then send nothing over the network to another machine.

so i was looking for image compare code and found many but no one deliver code in such way to form third image with difference. so my question is that when difference will be send to second machine then second machine should form third image with difference image data along with previous image data.

no logic is coming to my mind to write code which stitch the difference in data with previous image. please help me with concept or code. thanks

Comment: This is not a "do my homework platform"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a start, you can look into [AForge Difference Class](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/673023f7-799a-2ef6-7933-31ef09974dde.htm):

> Difference filter - get the difference between overlay and source images.

Answer (score 2):

One trivial way to break the screen up into tiles -- say, each 40x40 pixels in size (I just made this up).

Then, for each tile, simply compare it with the previous tile and only send the "dirty" tiles, along with their positions.

This approach can also be trivially extended to work in a dynamic fashion (e.g. split-in-quarters recursively). Also, don't forget image compression (e.g. PNG), which may actually benefit from sending larger *masked* tile groups.

Happy coding.

Comment: can u plzz provide code to break the screen image in few time and then compare each time with every other...i am not advance developer...so i just can not visualize the whole things.